# How do I convert a numeric vector into binary numbers?

Tags: r

I converted a factor into a numeric vector i.e. from "Male" and "Female" to "1" and "2" with the R code, "as.numeric(data$Gender)". However, I would like to convert the numeric vector into binary numbers i.e. from "1" representing "Male" and "2" representing "Female", to "1" representing "Male" and "0" representing "Female". Could anybody please kindly advice me on how this could be done? Thank you very much, and your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: `as.numeric(factor(c("male", "female"), levels=c("female", "male"))) - 1`

Answer (score 4):

Here are three alternatives:

Sample data:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(c("Male", "Female"), 10, TRUE)
x
#  [1] "Male"   "Male"   "Female" "Female" "Male"   "Female" "Female" "Female" "Female" "Male"
```

#### Option 1: Use `==` (assumes that you only have these two options).

```
as.numeric(x == "Male")
#  [1] 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

---

#### Option 2: Use a named key.

```
key <- setNames(0:1, c("Female", "Male"))
key[x]
#   Male   Male Female Female   Male Female Female Female Female   Male 
#      1      1      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      1
```

---

#### Option 3: Use `factor` specifying the labels.

```
factor(x, c("Male", "Female"), labels = c(1, 0))
#  [1] 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
# Levels: 1 0
```

Note that you'll still need `as.numeric(as.character())` if you wanted a numeric vector:

```
as.numeric(as.character(factor(x, c("Male", "Female"), labels = c(1, 0))))
#  [1] 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: Roughly the same as option one, but a little faster in some instances, I believe is `+(x == "Male")`.

Comment: @lmo, Thanks. I'm aware of that trick, however, in my opinion, the benefits of a very marginal increase in speed over using `as.numeric` do not outweigh the benefits of more explicit code. Taking it one step further, you can use `as.integer` instead of `as.numeric`, which is closer in performance to `+` (surpassing it in most of my tests).